# Can you avoid querying for a texture location in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, texture, shader, c++

The way I learnt to send a texture to a shader is more or less

```
//Use program
//Bind texture to the texture unit to its appropriate target
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + texture_unit);
glBindTexture(target, textureID);
//Get the uniform location in the program and attach the texture unit
GLuint location = /*get the location somewhow*/;
glUniform1i(location,texture_unit);
```

However when dealing with buffers and SSBOS rather than trying to find a location through a string name, the object is declared as:

```
layout(std430, binding = 2) buffer texture_meta_data
```

For example. This means that the SSBO is to be bound at binding point 2

And then on the C++ side one does something like

```
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 2, SSBOID);
```

To bind the object to the binding point.

How can you do the same with textures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the [exact same syntax](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Version_4.20_binding) as you did for SSBOs:

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D texture_name;
```

This is a GL 4.2 feature, so if you can use SSBOs, you can use this.